# GPO Access Denied (Security Filtering)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am working on a GPO but i am having a some trouble. Basically, I am attempting to load a list of email addresses to user's Junk E-Mail Safe Senders lists.

However, GPRESULT displays access denied in the "Denied GPO's" under User Configuration Summary" when the GPO is linked to an OU.

Access Denied (Security Filtering)

Here are my specs:

DC: Server 2008 R2
Client: Windows 7

Scope: Linked to OU (containing users)
Security Filtering:  Authenticated Users
Delegation: Authenticated Users - Read and Apply

Here are most of the GPO settings:

GPO: User Configuration 
Administrative Template, Microsoft Outlook 2010 (and 2013)/Outlook Options/Preferences/Junk E-mail
-Specify full path and filename to Safe Senders list
-Trigger to apply junk email list settings
Preferences, Windows Settings, Registry: Key path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail, Value name: JunkMailImportLists) 
-Plus a few other related registry changes

A few things I have noticed.  First, the GPO is applied to a specific User Account (User1), which i believe has elevated privileges or was even domain admin at one time.  All other users (User2) fail to receive the GPO and get the Access Denied.

Also, if I link the GPO to the domain level, neither user (User1 or User2) receive the GPO.

I have searched everywhere and tried a number of different configurations without success.  Please help.

Comment: Did you try running a GPRESULT /h and see which settings did apply?

Comment: Did you check and set the correct permissions to the registry key? HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail

Comment: You need to provide ALL of the access control entries from the security advanced dialog.